# Python day 7 of 100 days of code false variable

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, do-while

Hi I'm trying to understand the logic behind the code. Why do I have to set the while loop to not false for it to run? (1) Please help me with the logic behind this (2) is there an easier alternative way to do the same? Also, this is a while loop to ask for user input until the word is guessed correctly

```
end_of_game = False

while not end_of_game:

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
```

Comment: You only enter the “while” loop when the thing you’re evaluating is true. For example, “while False” will never enter the while loop.

Comment: We can't reproduce a runnable program from your example.

Comment: Try `game_running = True`, `while game_running:` instead. It's the same, just different. The naming of your variables has an influence on what the start value is and how the loop is formulated. Same in proper English: you can ask someone whether they want to continue playing or you can ask whether they want to stop playing. In one case, the answer is "Yes" while the same result for the other question is "No".

Comment: How does "Python day 7 of 100 days" relate to the question? Is that of any importance? If not, please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so `end_of_game` is a Boolean which simply holds if the game has reached it's end or not. So by default, we set it to false as the game can't end before it has even begun. We want to keep playing the game as long as the game has not ended. So with while loops, as long as the condition passed to them is true, they continue to loop or in this case, it continues to play the game. So we want to continue playing the game *while* the it is not the end of the game (`end_of_game == false`). To continue looping through, we need the condition to be true, hence we need to make the false `end_of_game` condition true. We achieve this with the `not`.

Here's another way to look at it that may be simpler:

```
game_in_progress = True

while game_in_progress:

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

A while loop executes while the condition is `True`. You're not setting anything in the loop to `False` - since `end_of_game` is `False`, `not end_of_game` is `True`.

Comment: Maybe you want to answer the second part of the question as well. You can take my comment and integrate it into your answer, if you like.